# Upper bound for Bilinear form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products, bilinear-form, spectral-norm

Let $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. It is clear (e.g., by Cauchy-Schwarz) that, $|\langle x,Ay\rangle|\leqslant \|A\|\cdot \|x\|\cdot \|y\|$.

Now, I'm interested in a slightly stronger version of this object. Is it true that, for every $x,y,A$:
$$
|\langle x,Ay\rangle|\leqslant \|A\|\cdot |\langle x,y\rangle|?
$$

Comment: The descriptor you're looking for is not "more general", but "stronger".

Comment: edited. (by the way such a hard nickname! ;))

Comment: You might like to know that if you just write @Omn (i.e. the beginning of a username), I (or the relevant user) will get pinged if I'm in the thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  For instance, consider
$$
A = \pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}, \quad x = \pmatrix{1\\0}, \quad y = \pmatrix{0\\1}.
$$